# how to print all global instances of a c++ class with gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I want to know probable values of a field of a class. So I want to print this property of all instances. But how can I find all instances of a class? So that I can see reasonable values of a field of the class.

Comment: Please define "all", since some instance might be constructed in stack. If you want to know all of them. I suggest to create a table in the constructor.

Comment: Real question is: why? What is your actual problem? How this should help you?

Comment: If you don't add some code to your constructors, no chance! The executable itself does not track this. Even so there is no entry in the debug sections for such an topic.

Comment: If it's a virtual class you could search the memory for the virtual table pointer.